# akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.HttpContactPointBootstrap - Probing failed. How can it be solved?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

How can I solve this problem -- I am trying to run akka cluster on minikube. But failed to create a cluster.

```
17:46:49.093 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] WARN akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.HttpContactPointBootstrap - Probing [http://172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:8558/bootstrap/seed-nodes] failed due to: Tcp command [Connect(172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:8558,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

My config is --

```
akka {
actor {
    provider = cluster
}

cluster {
    shutdown-after-unsuccessful-join-seed-nodes = 60s
}
coordinated-shutdown.exit-jvm = on

management {
cluster.bootstrap {
    contact-point-discovery {
      discovery-method = kubernetes-api
    }
}
}
```

}

my yaml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: appka
  name: appka
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: appka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: appka
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: appka
        image: akkacluster:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ready
            port: management
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 10
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /alive
            port: management
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 10
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
        ports:
        - name: management
          containerPort: 8558
          protocol: TCP
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        - name: remoting
          containerPort: 25520
          protocol: TCP
          
          
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
  
  
  
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:serviceaccount:default:default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Unfortunately my cluster is not formaing---

```
 kubectl logs pod/appka-7c4b7df7f7-5v7cc
17:46:32.026 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
SLF4J: A number (1) of logging calls during the initialization phase have been intercepted and are
SLF4J: now being replayed. These are subject to the filtering rules of the underlying logging system.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#replay
17:46:33.644 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.remote.artery.tcp.ArteryTcpTransport - Remoting started with transport [Artery tcp]; listening on address [akka://appka@172.17.0.4:25520] with UID [-8421566647681174079]
17:46:33.811 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.cluster.Cluster - Cluster Node [akka://appka@172.17.0.4:25520] - Starting up, Akka version [2.6.14] ...
17:46:34.491 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.cluster.Cluster - Cluster Node [akka://appka@172.17.0.4:25520] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
17:46:34.512 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.cluster.Cluster - Cluster Node [akka://appka@172.17.0.4:25520] - Started up successfully
17:46:34.883 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.cluster.Cluster - Cluster Node [akka://appka@172.17.0.4:25520] - No downing-provider-class configured, manual cluster downing required, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster.html#downing
17:46:34.884 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.cluster.Cluster - Cluster Node [akka://appka@172.17.0.4:25520] - No seed nodes found in configuration, relying on Cluster Bootstrap for joining
17:46:39.084 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11] INFO akka.management.internal.HealthChecksImpl - Loading readiness checks [(cluster-membership,akka.management.cluster.scaladsl.ClusterMembershipCheck), (sharding,akka.cluster.sharding.ClusterShardingHealthCheck)]
17:46:39.090 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11] INFO akka.management.internal.HealthChecksImpl - Loading liveness checks []
17:46:39.104 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO ClusterListenerActor$ - started actor akka://appka/user - (class akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorRefAdapter)
17:46:39.888 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement - Binding Akka Management (HTTP) endpoint to: 172.17.0.4:8558
17:46:40.525 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement - Including HTTP management routes for ClusterHttpManagementRouteProvider
17:46:40.806 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement - Including HTTP management routes for ClusterBootstrap
17:46:40.821 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.ClusterBootstrap - Using self contact point address: http://172.17.0.4:8558
17:46:40.914 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement - Including HTTP management routes for HealthCheckRoutes
17:46:44.198 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.ClusterBootstrap - Initiating bootstrap procedure using kubernetes-api method...
17:46:44.200 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.ClusterBootstrap - Bootstrap using `akka.discovery` method: kubernetes-api
17:46:44.226 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement - Bound Akka Management (HTTP) endpoint to: 172.17.0.4:8558
17:46:44.487 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator - Locating service members. Using discovery [akka.discovery.kubernetes.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery], join decider [akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider], scheme [http]
17:46:44.490 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator - Looking up [Lookup(appka,None,Some(tcp))]
17:46:44.493 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO akka.discovery.kubernetes.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery - Querying for pods with label selector: [app=appka]. Namespace: [default]. Port: [None]
17:46:45.626 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator - Looking up [Lookup(appka,None,Some(tcp))]
17:46:45.627 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] INFO akka.discovery.kubernetes.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery - Querying for pods with label selector: [app=appka]. Namespace: [default]. Port: [None]
17:46:48.428 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator - Located service members based on: [Lookup(appka,None,Some(tcp))]: [ResolvedTarget(172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/172.17.0.4)), ResolvedTarget(172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/172.17.0.3))], filtered to [172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local:0, 172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:0]
17:46:48.485 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator - Located service members based on: [Lookup(appka,None,Some(tcp))]: [ResolvedTarget(172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/172.17.0.4)), ResolvedTarget(172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/172.17.0.3))], filtered to [172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local:0, 172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:0]
17:46:48.586 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider - Discovered [2] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying
17:46:49.092 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] WARN akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.HttpContactPointBootstrap - Probing [http://172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local:8558/bootstrap/seed-nodes] failed due to: Tcp command [Connect(172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local:8558,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
17:46:49.093 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] WARN akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.HttpContactPointBootstrap - Probing [http://172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:8558/bootstrap/seed-nodes] failed due to: Tcp command [Connect(172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:8558,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
17:46:49.603 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider - Discovered [2] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying
17:46:49.682 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator - Looking up [Lookup(appka,None,Some(tcp))]
17:46:49.683 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] INFO akka.discovery.kubernetes.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery - Querying for pods with label selector: [app=appka]. Namespace: [default]. Port: [None]
17:46:49.726 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] INFO akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator - Located service members based on: [Lookup(appka,None,Some(tcp))]: [ResolvedTarget(172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/172.17.0.4)), ResolvedTarget(172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/172.17.0.3))], filtered to [172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local:0, 172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:0]
17:46:50.349 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] WARN akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.HttpContactPointBootstrap - Probing [http://172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:8558/bootstrap/seed-nodes] failed due to: Tcp command [Connect(172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local:8558,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
17:46:50.504 [appka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11] WARN akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.HttpContactPointBootstrap - Probing [http://172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local:8558/bootstrap/seed-nodes] failed due to: Tcp command [Connect(172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local:8558,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing akka.remote setting block. Something like:

```
akka {
  actor {
    # provider=remote is possible, but prefer cluster
    provider = cluster 
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      transport = tcp # See Selecting a transport below
      canonical.hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      canonical.port = 25520
    }
  }
}
```